# JavaScript inset variable into brackets

Tags: javascript

when I alert btnName it is not fetching the attr name and instead using the text btnName.

```
var btnName = orderBtn.attr("name");
var obj = {btnName:true,json:1};
```

I am sure this is possible, I just can;t figure it out.

Comment: Do you mean `obj` is using "btnName" (literally) as the name for the attribute?

Comment: Yes when I view this in Firebug it is the same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 var btnName = orderBtn.attr ("name");
 var obj = { json: 1 };
 obj [btnName] = true;
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to write it like this:

```
var obj = {json: 1}
obj[orderBtn.attr('name')] = true
```

There's no way to include an expression (such as a variable) as a key when constructing an object using literal notation.

```
var obj = {foo: 'bar'}
```

is essentially shorthand for

```
var obj = {'foo': 'bar'}
```

If you want to refer to a variable `foo`, you need square bracket notation:

```
var obj = {}
obj[foo] = 'bar'
```

Answer (score 0):

Use brackets if you want to use a variable as a key:

```
 var obj = { json: 1 };
 obj[btnName] = true;
```